# Kafka Connect Debezium postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to connect a Postgres SQL db hosted in Amazon RDS with a Kafka topic using Debezium.

I am following the following tutorial :

http://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/

My kafka and kafka connect services start up fine and the kafka connect service also picks up my debezium postgres connector jars in /usr/share/java dir.

However on trying to attach the postgres config json via the kafka connect  API using the following curl command :

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @connector1.json
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
 [2018-06-13 23:45:44,749] ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not intialize type registry
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.<init>(PostgresConnection.java:68)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector.validate(PostgresConnector.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:277)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$6.call(DistributedHerder.java:534)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$6.call(DistributedHerder.java:531)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:267)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:161)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:585)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.<init>(PostgresConnection.java:65)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
    ... 18 more
```

Could some please advice on the exception and how to resolve it?

Is there a property/configuratuion that I may be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have postgres database port configured to be accessible from outside?
IIRC RDS database uses SSL for connection so it might be necessary to configure SSL also in postgres connector.

Comment: Hey @Jiri Pechanec Thanks for your pointer! That indeed was the issue. The issue was resolved when I used an internal IP instead of an external facing IP. The connector got picked up by the Kafka Connect service after doing changing the host.